# Math riddle question please

Tags: mathematics, pattern

My husband and I cannot figure out this mathematical riddle, to save our lives, despite him being a math teacher.
The riddle is as follows:

8898=7,

4566=2,

1203=1,

4566=2,

5464=1,

7774=0,

9856=4,

8764=3,

4500=?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @DennisMeng In the riddle, how is the number "4" written?  Does it appear as if on a digital clock, or does it have the enclosed "triangle" space?

Comment: If it is the same, the 4 would break it. It could be phrased differently...

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this may be tricky to explain due to font issues, but it would make sense if written out with a stick figure 4 (open) rather than the typical font 4 (closed).

In every instance, it is the

> number of holes or circular like openings in the number.

For the first example:

> $8 = 2$, $8 = 2$, $9 = 1$, $8 = 2$ for a total of 7

So the final answer would be:

> $4500 = 2$

Comment: No problem. Even if it was a duplicate, I figured an answer would not hurt (as the other indicates the 4 as counting)